# unable to use string attribute in artff file weka and build classifier

Tags: java, weka

Hi I am using Weka for machine learning and my artff file format is like below

```
`@relation datastest

@attribute fwoh {what, when, where, how, who, why}
@attribute parameter {color, performance}
@attribute object { power, cost}
@attribute model {x,y,z}
@attribute question String`
```

I tried using J48, PART,DecisionTable, ZeroR and SMO, all the classifier throw me below exception when I build classifier.

```
weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException: weka.classifiers.rules.ZeroR: Cannot handle string class!
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1164)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1303)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1208)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.testWithFail(Capabilities.java:1506)
    at weka.classifiers.rules.ZeroR.buildClassifier(ZeroR.java:122)
    at wekaproject.TextCategorizationTest.main(TextCategorizationTest.java:66)
```

I build classifier as below

```
final Instances data = new Instances(readDataFile("questions.txt"));
final Classifier classifier = new SMO();
classifier.buildClassifier(data );
```

Can anyone tell me what is the classifier should I use. And should i use StringToWordVector. I tried using StringToVector but doesnt help me. Can anyone tell me how to use StringToVector, if needed one.

**Updat:**
This is the input arff file

```
@relation 'text_files_in_C:\\Desktop\\test'

@attribute id {a,b,c}
@attribute ids {g,h,i}
@attribute idss {k,l,m}
@attribute contents string

@data
a,g,k,'x'
b,h,l'y'
c,i,m,'z'
```

This is the output arff file after filtering

```
@relation 'text_files_in_C:\\Desktop\\test-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector-D.,:\\\'\\\"()?!-R4-W1000000-C-T-N1-L-stemmerweka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer-M1'

@attribute id {a,b,c}
@attribute ids {g,h,i}
@attribute idss {k,l,m}
@attribute x numeric
@attribute y numeric
@attribute z numeric

@data
{3 0.693147}
{0 b,1 h,2 l,4 0.693147}
{0 c,1 i,2 m,5 0.693147}
```

Instance I am trying to test

```
@relation 'text_files_in_C:\\Desktop\\test'

@attribute id {a,b,c}
@attribute ids {g,h,i}
@attribute idss {k,l,m}
@attribute contents string

@data
b,h,l,'x'
c,i,m,'y'
```

This is my Java code

```
package wekaproject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

import weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes;
import weka.classifiers.functions.SMO;
import weka.classifiers.rules.DecisionTable;
import weka.classifiers.rules.PART;
import weka.classifiers.rules.ZeroR;
import weka.classifiers.trees.J48;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.SerializationHelper;
import weka.core.converters.ArffSaver;
import weka.core.stemmers.LovinsStemmer;
import weka.core.stemmers.Stemmer;
import weka.core.stopwords.WordsFromFile;
import weka.core.tokenizers.NGramTokenizer;
import weka.filters.Filter;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToNominal;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector;

public class TestWeka {


    public static BufferedReader readDataFile(String filename) {
        BufferedReader inputReader = null;

        try {
            inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("File not found: " + filename);
        }

        return inputReader;
    }

    public static void main(final String [] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Running");

        final StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();
        final ZeroR classifier = new ZeroR(); 
        final Instances data = new Instances(readDataFile("test.arff"));
        data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

        // Use filter.
        String[] options = new String[2];
        options[0] = "-R";                                    // "range"
        options[1] = "4";  
        filter.setOptions(options);


        filter.setInputFormat(data);
        Instances filteredData = Filter.useFilter(data, filter);
        filteredData.setClassIndex(0);
        // Rebuild classifier.
        classifier.buildClassifier(filteredData);
                 ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
                 saver.setInstances(data);
                 saver.setFile(new File("input_test_filtered.arff"));
                 saver.writeBatch();

        Instances testInstances=new Instances(readDataFile("test2.arff"));
        testInstances.setClassIndex(testInstances.numAttributes()-1);
        Instances filteredTestData=Filter.useFilter(testInstances, filter);
        filteredTestData.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes()-1);
         saver = new ArffSaver();
         saver.setInstances(testInstances);
         saver.setFile(new File("output_test_filtered.arff"));
         saver.writeBatch();

        for (int j = 0; j < filteredTestData.numInstances(); j++) {
        double value = classifier.classifyInstance(filteredTestData.instance(j));
        System.out.println("value::" + value);
        // get the prediction percentage or distribution
        double[] percentage = classifier.distributionForInstance(filteredTestData.instance(j));

        String prediction = data.classAttribute().value((int) value);

        for (int i = 0; i < percentage.length; i = i + 1) {
            System.out.println("Probability of class " + data.classAttribute().value(i)
                    + " : " + Double.toString(percentage[i]));
        }
        System.out.println("The predicted value of instance " + Integer.toString(j) + ": " + prediction);

    }
    }

} // End of the class //
```

I always get X as the result when i do classify instance. Any help is much appreciated!!!

**updated code**

```
package wekaproject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

import weka.classifiers.functions.LibLINEAR;
import weka.core.DenseInstance;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffSaver;
import weka.filters.Filter;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToNominal;

public class demo1 {
    public demo1() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        BufferedReader breader = null;
        breader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "test.arff"));
        Instances Train = new Instances(breader);
        //Train.setClassIndex(Train.numAttributes() - 1); // comment out this line
        LibLINEAR kMeans = new LibLINEAR();


        StringToNominal  filter=new StringToNominal();
        String options[]=new String[2];
        options[0]="-R";
        options[1]="4";
        filter.setInputFormat(Train);






        Instances traineData=Filter.useFilter(Train, filter);
        traineData.setClassIndex(4);
        kMeans.buildClassifier(traineData);

        breader.close();

        ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
         saver.setInstances(traineData);
         saver.setFile(new File("output_test_filtered2.arff"));
         saver.writeBatch();

        Instance instance = new DenseInstance(4);
        instance.setDataset(traineData);
        instance.setValue(0, "what");
        instance.setValue(1, "car");
        instance.setValue(2, "green");
        instance.setValue(3, "y");

        double value = kMeans.classifyInstance(instance);
        System.out.println("value::" + value);

        double[] percentage = kMeans.distributionForInstance(instance);

        String prediction = traineData.classAttribute().value((int) value);

        for (int i = 0; i < percentage.length; i = i + 1) {
            System.out.println("Probability of class " + traineData.classAttribute().value(i)
                    + " : " + Double.toString(percentage[i]));
        }
        System.out.println("The predicted value of instance " + Integer.toString(0) + ": " + prediction);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new demo1();
    }
}
```

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/weka/7753/text-classification#t=201611250848340855332

Comment: Hi I tried based on above link, I am able to build classifier and save model. But again when i try to classify instance, i always get the result of 1 row in data. Could you please help me

Comment: Also I couldnt find the liblinear classifier in weka3.8, I am using ZeroR classifier.

Comment: LibLinear is not preinstalled in weka. You have to install LibLinear classifier through package manager. Or include the java jar to your project from here http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/   ZeroR classifier just predicts the majority class so thats(probably) the reason you get result of 1.

Comment: Hi, I downloaded LibLinear dependencies and used it as classifier. But now it gives me a exception like "Exception in thread "main" weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException: weka.classifiers.functions.LibLINEAR: Cannot handle string class!". Could you please help me, Since I am new to weka I am struggling to get it fixed.

Comment: The updated code above did the trick. I need to use StringtoNominal rather Stringtowordvector. Thank you so much for the support.

Comment: Thanks. You can upvote the documentation link i have sent you if you found it useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the StringToNominal Filter to convert the "class attribute".
The command line call is

`weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToNominal -R last`

At this time I don't know exactly how to call it from inside Java code.